# Интересуют три тире (на месте ли), но вынуждена дать расширенный контекст, - поможете со знаками?

Tags: пунктуация

> Кстати, работа с аффективной памятью – единственное, что роднит такие
>   разные школы. Только этот феномен Станиславский считал одним из
>   множества инструментов актёрского мастерства и называл «живой
>   памятью», а Ли Страсберг возвёл на этом фундаменте целое здание
>   метода. Но возможно, его школа воспитывает исключительно киноактёров?
>   В кино, где нередко первой снимают финальную сцену, а встречу героев –
>   когда придётся, – самое оно! И, конечно, в кино их актёрские фокусы
>   выглядят весьма правдоподобно. Доказательством тому – величайшие
>   выпускники. Но, на мой взгляд, эта система совершенно непригодна в
>   театре. На русской сцене, в русской традиции – уж точно…

*...Первой снимают финальную сцену, а встречу героев **–**
когда придётся, **–** самое оно!*

*...в русской традиции – уж точно…*

Можно и так, но не предложите ли более точные знаки?

Comment: А не противоречиво ли "только этот... считал одним из множества"? Лучше "относил к числу инструментов". Этот (где он, "этот" или хотя бы "тот"?) фундамент -> _его_ фундамент - если первое упоминание слова. "Самое оно" висит в воздухе.

Comment: Сашка ты посте этого, вотъ. Почему некий феномен не может быть одним из множества инструментов актёрского мастерства? *Ли Страсберг возвёл на этом фундаменте целое здание метода*:  фундамент для Ли - работа с аффективной памятью! *Самое оно!* - аффективная, или, по Станиславскому, живая память. Для кино - самое оно!

Comment: Для того, чтобы сослаться на "это", надо его сначала назвать по имени. Можно, конечно, дурь услышать вроде выражения "в _этой_ связи" (какой, случайной?) или сапогосмятности "я тебе в _том_ числе вот что скажу...", но не в печатном же виде! Некий феномен "может" множествовать, но не в единственном числе ("только") - разгадать смысл можно, но каламбур остаётся. Всё равно непонятно, как и к чему именно в тексте привязано "самое оно", хотя и можно сказать, что это спонтанное выражение оптимизма по отношению ко всему ранее сказанному.

Comment: "Самое оно!" -  это и есть спонтанное выражение оптимизма по отношению ко всему ранее сказанному.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Галина, хотела исправить кое-что, а получилось, что всё переделала. Поэтому это вариант, который, с моей точки зрения, удобно читается. Возможно, вам что-то пригодится.

Но, возможно, его школа воспитывает исключительно киноактёров? В кино, где нередко первой снимают финальную сцену, а встречу героев – когда придётся, это и есть самое оно? Конечно, в кино их "актёрские фокусы" выглядят весьма правдоподобно, и  доказательством тому – величайшие выпускники. Но, на мой взгляд, эта система совершенно непригодна в театре, а  на русской сцене, в русской традиции – уж точно…

Comment: Ааа! Переделывать нельзя! Я так жизнь положу на переписывание многоглавной книги!

Comment: Ну тогда  хотя бы с двумя первыми тире  надо разобраться, мне кажется, что они совсем не на месте. Я даже смысл не сразу поняла, думала, что это вставка.

Comment: Жду разбора, как соловей!

Comment: Про вставку уже сказала. Про второй вопросительный знак: это вопрос или утверждение (мне кажется, что вопрос). Дробление текста кое-где кажется необоснованным, лучше использовать ССП для связности мыслей. Присоединительные союзы: союз И не обособляется. а союз НО факультативен, но всё же чаще обособляется.